# C++ Inheritances - Files

Tags: c++, class

Im trying to seperate a class and its superclass into two different header and cpp files. In the main Method I want to include both of them.

Currently my main programm **example.cpp** looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   Rectangle Rect;

   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);

   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**My Rectangle.cpp like this:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;


int getArea()
{ 
    return (Shape::width * Shape::height); 
}
```

**And my Rectangle.h:**

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
      int getArea();
};
```

The Shape.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

void Shape::setWidth(int w)
{
    width = w;
}

void Shape::setHeight(int h)
{
    height = h;
}
```

**And the Shape.h:**

```
class Shape 
{
public:
    void setWidth(int w);
    void setHeight(int h);
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

The **header.h** just includes the two headers of the classes:

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
```

If I compile it, the compiler says:

```
Lukass-MacBook-Pro:Oberklassenbeispiel Lukas$ g++ -c Rectangle.cpp
Rectangle.cpp:9:17: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'width'
        return (Shape::width * Shape::height); 
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~
Rectangle.cpp:9:32: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'height'
        return (Shape::width * Shape::height); 
                               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

It seems, that the `Rectanlge.cpp` cant see the attributes of the superclass. How do I fix this?

Comment: Answer to first question: Yes. About second question: What is *main method*? Do you mean `main` function? You don't include anything in a function. *How* doesen't your code work? What did you expect, how does the behaviour differ?

Comment: You access width and height as if they were fields in the Rectangle class, i.e. unqualified (`return width * height; `). Ah yes, and don't use brackets for return values, it looks so inexperienced ;-)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the code violates an important style rule. Each file should `#include` every header that it needs. So  Rectangle.h should start out with `#include "Shape.h"`. The code here works because in the places where Rectangle.h is used, the `#include "Rectangle.h"` is preceded by `#include "Shape.h"`. That's brittle, and sooner or later you'll regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you #include, you provide the file name, not the classes specified in the file.   It is quite common to have multiple closely coupled classes in a single file.   Your example isn't really the best (it is single inheritance, not multiple as the title suggests), but working with that...

You could have a file, shapes.h with the following contents :

```
class Shape 
{
public:
      void setWidth(int w)
      {
          width = w;
      }
    void setHeight(int h)
    {
       height = h;
    }
 protected:
    int width;
    int height;
};

// Derived class
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
    int getArea()
    { 
        return (width * height); 
    }
};
```

Then in your main function (and the file containing it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shapes.h"
int main(void)
{
   Rectangle Rect;

   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);

   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```